# HTML, CSS problem with Chrome

Tags: html, css

On site http://www.paka-pikk.ee/ the left menu isnt shown properly in Google Chrome. In Firefox (blue) menu bottom part is in the right place. In Chrome, its in the middle of the menu. What could be the problem, code is the same.

Comment: you need to give us some code (html and css)

Comment: The code in reachable via site, right click and source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, changing `valign="top"` to `valign="bottom"` on the `<td>` that contains the menu `<table>` fixes it and also still works in Firefox.

Comment: Thanks dude, it helped! Can you explain why it helps or something...just to know next time? :)

Comment: At the moment, I can't determine why it was broken! I am still looking :-)

Comment: There is definitely a display issue between Firefox and Chrome as the overall menu is lower in Chrome. Chrome is also showing a warning on the CSS `background` image for that element, so that could explain it. I'm not sure why Chrome is showing the warning when _Inspecting_ the element.